# Please help, after flutter update, (The name 'MenuItem' is defined in the libraries) in visual studio

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

When I updated Flutter, I had this problem in more than one project.

the error message:

```
The name 'MenuItem' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_menu_bar.dart' and 'package:fuodz/widgets/menu_item.dart'.
```

Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejc1E.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try use as prefix

```
import "package:fuodz/widgets/menu_item.dart" as item;

//code widget

VStack[
  item.MenuItem();
]
```

or, change class name `MenuItem` in `widgets/menu_item.dart` to different name

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Yourprojectname/model/menu_item.dart' as item;

class MenuItems{  
  static List<item.MenuItem> itemFirst = [
    itemShare,
  ]; 
  static List<item.MenuItem> itemSecond = [
    itemSignOut,
  ];
  static const itemShare = item.MenuItem(
    text: 'Alarm',
    icon: Icons.alarm,
  );
  static const itemSignOut = item.MenuItem(
    text: 'Sign Out',
    icon: Icons.logout,
  );
}
```